# Laravel count is not working, any support?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to output user details on api i am using laravel 6 but `count` is giving me unexpected output may be it is not woking so i don't how any one can help

```
    public function userDetails(User $user, Request $req){

        $user = $user->find($req->username);

        if(empty($user))//check if user exists
            return response()->json(["msg"=>"No user found "],404);

        $user->profile = empty($user->profile) ? "" : $user->profile->file;
        $user->downloads = empty($user->downloads) ? 0 : $user->downloads->count('id');
        $user->likes = empty($user->likes) ? 0 : $user->likes->count();
        $user->reads = empty($user->reads) ? 0 : $user->reads->count();
        $user->dislikes = empty($user->dislikes) ? 0 : $user->dislikes->count();

        return response()->json($user, 200);
    }
```

output

```
{
"username": "liberi",
"firstName": null,
"secondName": null,
"gender": null,
"phone": "0987654321",
"email": "liberi@gmail.com",
"created_at": "2020-05-12 21:48:33",
"updated_at": "2020-05-12 21:48:33",
"email_verified_at": null,
"phone_verified_at": null,
"profile": null,
"downloads": [],
"likes": [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "book_ISBN": "09876543236",
      "user_username": "liberi",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
   },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "book_ISBN": "09876543236",
     "user_username": "liberi",
    "created_at": null,
   "updated_at": null
  }
],
"reads": [],
"dislikes": []
}
```

expected out put

```
{
"username": "liberi",
"firstName": null,
"secondName": null,
"gender": null,
"phone": "0987654321",
"email": "liberi@gmail.com",
"created_at": "2020-05-12 21:48:33",
"updated_at": "2020-05-12 21:48:33",
"email_verified_at": null,
"phone_verified_at": null,
"profile": null,
"downloads": 0,
"likes": 2,
"reads": 0,
"dislikes": 0
}
```

Comment: You may need to do like so: `$user->likes()->count()`. Note the parentheses.

Comment: it is giving me the same

Comment: Can't be giving you the same, this is the same as the accepted answer :)

Comment: i checked well and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it easier to use the query builder to get the count instead of the relationship/collection, by adding the parenthesis on the relationship. You can even skip the ternary.

```
$user->downloads = $user->downloads()->count('id');
$user->likes = $user->likes()->count();
$user->reads = $user->reads()->count();
$user->dislikes = $user->dislikes()->count();
```

Comment: it worked i checked well your answer and found it  helping me

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `withCount()`. Check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

```
$user = User::find($req->username)->withCount('likes')->get();
$user->likes_count // this will give you user's like count
```